# Как сделать radio button чекнутым и перейти по ссылке без js

Tags: html, css, radiobutton

стоит задача на чистом css/html сделать меню, чтоб при нажатии на ссылку из списка меню выполнялся скролл к нужному блоку и ссылка на которую был сделан клик была выделена как активная, единственное, что мне пришло в голову, это сделать ссылки меню через radio button и в лейбл поставить ссылку, чтоб при клике на ссылку по id выполнялся скролл к нужному месту и выполнился выбор чекбокса, но то что у меня получилось в итоге это или скролл к нужному месту по нажатии на ссылку или выбор чекбокса

```css
#home {
  margin-top: 200px;
}

#aboutUs {
 margin-top: 400px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="radio"  name="menu" id="menuHome"/>
    <label for="menuHome">
   <a href="#home">Home</a>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="menu" id="menuAboutUs" />
    <label for="menuAboutUs">
      <a href="#aboutUs">About Us</a>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="home">Content 1</div>
<div id="aboutUs">Content 2</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yesvLxbo/

Comment: ничо не понял. checked:true?

Comment: ну, есть обычное меню со ссылками, например 'Home'  'About Us' 'Portfolio' 'Contacts', когда нажимаешь на 'About Us' происходит скролл к блоку с контектом который называется About Us, сама сылка после клика должна стать активной и выделаться например обычным underline  и она остается активной пока не нажмешь на другую ссылку в меню, я подумал что хороший вариант это сделать радиобатон с сылкой, застилизовать их как обычною кнопку, нажал на ссылку, произошел скролл, радиобаттон чекнулся по состоянию input:cheked могу застилизовать как активную ссылку

Comment: Это невозможно, только если программно